# Linux huge pages usage with Ignite for large physical memory

Tags: ignite, huge-pages

May Ignite benefit from Linux Huge pages (or Transparent Huge Pages)? 
Are there any recommendations (best practices?) for huge pages tuning for large physical memory size?

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to disable Transparent Huge Pages since it's already proved by many products and companies which build high load or in-memory solutions that this Linux feature can be a reason of latencies and long GC pauses. Refer to [this section](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning#gc-attacks-by-linux) for more information about the topic.